# How to hide and show rows in jquery datatable with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatable

I have a jquery datatable as follows:

```
<table id="dt_default" class="uk-table exclude_table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="aa">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>N1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bb">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>N1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cc">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>N1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dd">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>N1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a set of checkbox as follows, which is placed above the datatable:

```
<div>
     AA<input type="checkbox" class="exclude" value="aa">
     BB<input type="checkbox" class="exclude" value="analysis">
     CC<input type="checkbox" class="exclude" value="progress">
     DD<input type="checkbox" class="exclude" value="done">
</div>
```

What I need is: When a checkbox is checked the class corresponding to its value must hide from the table and when it is unchecked, it should show it back.

Eg: If you check the checkbox AA, the value corresponding to it is aa. So class aa must be hidden from table and when it is unchecked, it must show again.

The script I have tried for this is:

```
$('.exclude').click(function() { 
    $(".exclude").each(function(){
        if ($(this).prop('checked')==true)
        { 
            var hidden = $(this).attr("value");
            $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
            function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
                var row = oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr;
                return $(row).hasClass(hidden) ? false : true;
            }
            );
         }
        });                  
    });
```

This code is not working as expected.

What it does is, it hides the corresponding class when a checkbox is checked and we have to do either search/sort in datatable. It is not directly working when the checkbox is checked.

Also how to show the row back when checkbox is unchecked ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('.exclude').change(function () {
  $('#dt_default tr.' + $(this).val()).children('td').toggle();
});
```

Comment: On hide it will not correct the pagination. Eg: Page 1 of datatable has got 10 elements out of which 5 of them will go hidden on checking. Page 2 consist of only 2 elements. By this code what is going to happen is 5 will be shown in page 1 and 2 in page 2. It will not re-initiate datatable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one will work for you:

Guess we have this HTML:

```
<tr class="aa"><td>...</td></tr>
<tr class="bb"><td>...</td></tr>
<tr class="cc"><td>...</td></tr>
<input type="checkbox" id="aa" />
<input type="checkbox" id="bb" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cc" /> <!-- Be careful, your <tr> should have the same class that your checkbox has. -->
```

In this situation, We should have this JQuery code:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    var check_id = $(this).attr("id");
    if($(this).is(':checked') == true) {
        $("tr."+check_id).fadeOut();
    } else {
        $("tr."+check_id).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Point: You can check `value` attribute or any other thing to hide or show your tr . The most important thing is that `class` attribute of `tr` should be the same with the value of your `input` that you will check.

Comment: On hide it will not correct the pagination. Eg: Page 1 of datatable has got 10 elements out of which 5 of them will go hidden on checking. Page 2 consist of only 2 elements. By this code what is going to happen is 5 will be shown in page 1 and 2 in page 2. It will not re-initiate datatable.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham is your pagination based on JQuery or your programming language?

Comment: Jquery datatables default pagination